# Extension or Static Function?

Tags: c#, function, static

I'm developing a middle sized project, where performans is really important. I could not find (actually can not understand) the difference between static and extension functions.

e.g:

```
public static class My
{
    public static Vector2 MyTransform(this Vector2 point, float Rotation)
    {
        //....
       return MyVector;
    }

    public static Vector2 MyTransform(Vector2 point, float Rotation)
    {
        //....
       return MyVector;
    } 
}
```

These functions are used same only extension function is called over its instance:

1. Vector2 calc = myVector.MyTransform(0.45f);
2. Vector2 calc = My.MyTransform(myVector, 0.45f)

Which one do you prefer to use, or is prefered to use and why ?

Thanks !

Comment: If you're writing this, why not write `MyTransform()` in `Vector2` rather than in `My`?

Comment: There's no difference in the functions. It's just a personal preference on how you want to call the functions. An extension function can be called both ways, while a regular static function can only be called one way.

Comment: If this method needs an instance of Vector2, why is it `static`?

Comment: StuperUser my code is a sample, I have many extension functions, and the notation to define them is static in a static class

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There will be *no* difference in performance - a call to the extension method of

```
var result = foo.MyTransform(rotation);
```

will simply be converted by the compiler into:

```
var result = My.MyTransform(foo, rotation);
```

Now that's not to say that extension methods should be used *everywhere* - but it looks like this is an appropriate use case, unless you could *actually* make it an instance method on Rotation:

```
var result = rotation.Apply(foo);
```

(As an aside, I'd strongly urge you to reconsider your names, in order to follow .NET naming conventions.)

Answer (score 5):

Extension methods **ARE** static methods. They are just syntactic sugar. The compiler will create a normal call to the static method. This means, they are equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

The two functions are implemented in exactly the same way. Logically, however, extension methods let you [provide common functionality across multiple interfaces](http://dasblinkenlight.blogspot.com/2008/12/extension-methods-that-microsoft-added.html), so it is more than just a "syntactic sugar".

Answer (score 2):

They are called "Extension methods" and not extended.

An extension method is just a convenient way to have it appear like it was part of the object definition.

If you write:

```
public static void DoSomething(this MyObject myObject) { }
```

It means that you'll be able to call it like this, from an instance of `MyObject`:

```
myObject.DoSomething();
```

If you omit the `this` keyword in the method definition, you will not be able to call it like that, but only like this:

```
DoSomething(myObject);
```

Note that while the former call is possible only if you write the method as an extension method (with the `this` keyword), the latter is possible in both cases.